# Can we obtain ‘displacement vs time relation’ from a locus equation?

Tags: kinematics

Let’s say we know the equation of trajectory:

$\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1 $

Can we obtain $x$-$t$ relation (position-time) from the given locus equation if that’s all we have?

Comment: No, because there's no time in the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the equation only describes "allowed points" where the object can be (those for which the x and y coordinate fulfil the equation).

It's possible that the particle/object stays at (3|0) forever or that it moves along the path with constant tangential velocity or any other movement one can imagine. Unless that is given in addition to your equation, "there is no $t$".

Comment: Thanks. You said there is no $t$ in my equation, hence it's not possible to obtain the $x-t$ relation. Now I know why it's not possible. But don't quite understand this "there is no $t$". I mean, if there is $t$ in the equation, what would it look like? I'm not sure if I'm getting it across clearly. What I am asking is, if there is $time$ in the equation, how would it be given? What would the equation look like?

Comment: for example like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation. There will be multiple equations.